# How to clear values from range keeping headers in Google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Every week I need to clear some information from 5 worksheets. I have to keep the headers and some columns.

How do I just create a script in Googlesheet that I can click and will clear all the cells from A2 to G (until there is value) for 5 different worksheets?

Here is the link with an example with what has to be cleared up.
https://prnt.sc/2LpMWmb0esUd

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your link is not publicly accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the sheet name in an `array` and `loop` all the sheet to clear content on range `A2:G`.

Open script editor from your spreadsheet and use this sample script:-

```
function clear()
{
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   const sheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'] // your sheetNames
   sheets.forEach(s=> ss.getSheetByName(s).getRange('A2:G').clearContent() )
}
```

You can set a `timeBased` trigger for this function to run on a `weekly` bases.

Reference:-

[clearContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)

[Time Base Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

Answer (score 0):

#### Clear Sheets

```
function clear() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const shts = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'];
  shts.filter(sh => ~shts.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(sh => sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 7).clearContent());
}
```